# Canvas resize using Configure with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, configure

I want to create a Board Game with Python and Tkinter
I want it to has a resize-function but I have two canvases for the GUI. First one is the square-Board (`Spielfeld`), the second one is the place where I want to add the control buttons for the player (`Panel`)

So if I want to resize my Board using `<Configure>` in my Master Window, it shall draw the Canvas with the New Size (`self.FensterGroesse`)

The If-Case is working well when I pass the else -function in resize
but if I run the Programm with the else function it resizes itself until its 1px big. Not just the canvas, the whole window.

I know the problem is the `Panel` being one third as high as the Board and when `self.Panel.config` sets the new size `<Configure>` is activated again.

But I dont know how I can have these two sanvases, one is a square, the other is a rectangle with the same widht and the square bit just `0.3*height`

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI:

    def resize(self, event):
        if event.height > (event.width*1.3):
            self.FensterGroesse = event.width-2
        else:
            self.FensterGroesse = int(event.height/1.3)-2
        self.Spielfeld.config(height=self.FensterGroesse, width=self.FensterGroesse)
        self.Panel.config(height=self.FensterGroesse*0.3, width=self.FensterGroesse)
        self.Spielfeld.pack()
        self.Panel.pack()

    def __init__(self):
        self.FensterGroesse = 400
        self.tkinter = __import__("Tkinter")
        self.Master = self.tkinter.Tk()
        self.Spielfeld = self.tkinter.Canvas(self.Master, height=self.FensterGroesse,
                                             width=self.FensterGroesse, bg='#ffdead')
        self.Panel = self.tkinter.Canvas(self.Master, height=self.FensterGroesse*0.3,
                                         width=self.FensterGroesse, bg='brown')
        self.Spielfeld.pack()
        self.Panel.pack()
        self.Master.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.Master.mainloop()

GUI()
```

Comment: why are you trying to resize the canvas instead of letting tkinter do it? Are you trying to keep a specific aspect ratio?

Comment: yes, I want the first canvas to be a square with self.FensterGroesse as height & width   and the second canvas to be a rectangle with height = 0.3*self.FensterGroesse ; width = self.FensterGroesse